# Constructing every spanning tree from addition and deletion of edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, trees

Let $G = (V,E)$ be given (note that this is not necessarily simple), and consider the set of every spanning tree of $G$, $S$. Choose any $G_a, G_b \in S$. Is it possible to construct $G_b$ from $G_a$ by the following procedure?

1. Let $G_0 := G_a$, $n=0$
2. Choose an edge from $E$ that is not in $G_n$, and denote it $e$.
3. Adding an edge in a tree will create exactly one unique cycle. Choose an edge in this new cycle formed by $G_n \cup\{e\}$, and remove it. Denote it as $G_{n+1}$.
4. Set $n := n+1$
5. Repeat steps 2-4.

Since every spanning tree will have the same number of edges (namely, $|V|-1$), the edges contained in $G_a$ but not in $G_b$ and the edges contained in $G_b$ but not in $G_a$ have the same cardinality and are distinct. However, it is not guaranteed that the new cycle formed in Step 3 will contain an edge that is contained in $G_a$ but not in $G_b$ so that it can be removed. If it can be proven, then from Step 2 we can simply choose an edge that is contained in $G_b$ but not in $G_a$, and remove an edge that is contained in $G_a$ but not in $G_b$, and proceed. Or is there any other indirect way to show it?

Answer (score 2):

Every edge you see during the construction will be in either $G_a$ or $G_b$.

So if the new cycle you form on step 3 *doesn't* contain any edges outside $G_b$ it must be because the *entire* cycle consists of edges *in* $G_b$. But $G_b$, being a tree, does not contain any cycles -- contradiction!

Comment: What if $G$ is not a simple graph? Then it might not be the case where an edge selected is neither in $G_a$ nor $G_b$..

Comment: @Issac: Whoops, I misread your algorithm. I thought step 2 was "choose an edge from $G_b$ that is not in $G_n$". As it stands, I'm not convinced the algorithm even works ...

Comment: The question reads: "Is it possible to construct $G_b$ from $G_a$ by
the following procedure". Nobody says that the choices must be random.
So in step 2 always choose an edge that is in $G_b$ and not in $G_n$
and in step 2 always choose an edge that is not in $G_b$. Note that this is
always possible as long as $G_n$ and $G_b$ are different and each iteration
makes $G_n$ and $G_b$ share more edges. It does not matter that the graphs are not simple.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk: Oops, there is a typo. The third step should read:  "Choose an edge in this new cycle formed by $G_n \cup \{e\}$, and remove it." In this case it is not guaranteed to remove an edge that is in $G_a$ but not in $G_b$ unless G is a simple graph. The second step should be "Choose an edge that is not in $G_n$", instead of $G_a$; just made a change in the post.

Comment: @Issac: it does not matter: you still have a spanning tree after every step. Since $G_b$ does not have a cycle, you can remove an edge from the cycle that is not in $G_b$. So in every step you add an edge from $G_b$ and remove an edge that is not in $G_b$, bringing the iteration one step closer to $G_b$.